# use Jasypt in an Xpage

Tags: java, xpages-ssjs, jasypt

I would like to use Jasypt (a java library) in an Xpage to encrypt/decrypt some data.  [www.jasypt.org](http://www.jasypt.org/)

I copied the jar files into WebContent/WEB-INF/lib of my nsf file.

In my nsf I went to "Project Properties" "Java Build Path" "Libraries" "Add class folder" I added this folder to it.

On an Xpage I added a button and in the onclick event I've put:

```
userPassword = "test";
importPackage(StrongPasswordEncryptor);
passwordEncryptor = new StrongPasswordEncryptor();
encryptedPassword = passwordEncryptor.encryptPassword(userPassword);
viewScope.test = encryptedPassword;
```

I'm getting a reference error for StrongPasswordEncryptor

I guess I have to import the library in another way ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the **org.jasypt.util.password.StrongPasswordEncryptor** class, you have to write

```
importPackage(org.jasypt.util.password);
```

instead of

```
importPackage(StrongPasswordEncryptor);
```

As the name of the function suggests, you have to provide the package and not the class you want to import.

Comment: Now I get another error : Error calling method 'encryptPassword(string)' on java class 'org.jasypt.util.password.StrongPasswordEncryptor'

Comment: @MarcJonkers: First you should check if the encryptPassword function is defined: `typeof(passwordEncryptor.encryptPassword)==="function"`. If that is the case, the error is thrown inside that function and you should take a look at / provide us with the error details (for example the first lines of the stacktrace).